# Swagger OpenAPI array documentation in response

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

How a Json like this be documented inside response section in swagger?

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": "",
        "name": "James",
        "chat": "1",
        "messages": {
            "current": null,
            "count": null,
            "length": null,
            "rows": null,
            "type": null
        },
        "cid": "204",
        "cat": "messages",
        "mark": false
    }],
    "total": 200,
    "action": "success"
}
```

I tried

```
responses:
        '200':
          description: test data
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                example:
                  - id: null
                     name:  James
                      chat: 1
                        messages:
                         current:
                         count:
                         length: 
                         rows:
                         type:
                      cid: 204
                      cat: chat
                      mark: false
                  totalCount: 200
                  action: success
```

But show `error bad indentation of a mapping entry`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the expected object structure as a separate schema in the `#/components/schemas` section.

For example you name the resulting model `ResponseObj`, which has the properties `data`, `total` and `action`. The `data` property is another complex type with its own properties, so you also define a model for that type. This continues until you have defined all the models down to their simple property types.

Here is the definition for your example:

```
components:
  schemas:
    ResponseObj:
        properties:
          data:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/DataObj'
          total:
            type: string
          action:
            type: string
    DataObj:
        properties:
          id:
            type: string
          name:
            type: string
          chat:
            type: string
          messages:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/MessageObj'
          cid:
            type: number
          cat:
            type: string
          mark:
            type: boolean
    MessageObj:
        properties:
          current:
            type: string
          count:
            type: string
          length:
            type: number
          rows:
            type: number
          type:
            type: string
```

Now you can reference the `ResponseObj` model as the expected result of your operation:

```
paths:
  /example:
    get:
      responses:
        "200":
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ResponseObj'
```